# Count the number of blanks before current row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a row `is_blank` that indicates whether a row is `NaN` or not. I would like to generate a new feature that counts the number of `NaN` rows before current row within each set of records grouped by `id`.

An example below:

```
import pandas as pd
is_blank = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
id = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
outval = [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'is_blank': is_blank, 'outval': outval})
```

Here is how a toy dataset looks. I want to generate the `outval` column. `outval[3]` is 2 because there are two blanks before it. Then `outval[4]` resets to zero because there is no blank row before that row.

```
In[2]: test_df
Out[2]: 
    id  is_blank  outval
0    1         0       0
1    1         1       0
2    1         1       1
3    1         0       2
4    1         1       0
5    1         1       1
6    1         1       2
7    2         0       0
8    2         0       0
9    2         0       0
10   2         1       0
```

Currently I am trying some form of cumulative count like so:

```
In[3]: test_df.groupby(['id'])['is_blank'].cumsum().shift(1)
Out[3]: 
0     NaN
1     0.0
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     2.0
5     3.0
6     4.0
7     5.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
```

But obviously the counter does not reset within the group and ends up counting all blank rows. I am looking at `expanding_apply` option, but am unable to fully grasp how that works.

Any thoughts on how to solve this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vectorized approach

```
b = np.append(0, test_df.is_blank.values[:-1])
i = test_df.id.values

bc = b.cumsum()
w1 = np.where(b == 0)[0]
w2 = np.append(0, np.where(i[:-1] != i[1:])[0] + 1)
bd2 = bc[w2].repeat(np.diff(np.append(r[w2], k)))
bd1 = bc[w1].repeat(np.diff(np.append(r[w1], k)))

test_df.assign(outval=bc - np.fmax(bd1, bd2))

    id  is_blank  outval
0    1         0       0
1    1         1       0
2    1         1       1
3    1         0       2
4    1         1       0
5    1         1       1
6    1         1       2
7    2         0       0
8    2         0       0
9    2         0       0
10   2         1       0
```

The point of this is to find the positions at which a "reset" will happen.  That is when `id` changes and when `is_blank` is zero.

Let `bc` be the cumulative sum of `is_blank` and subtract the appropriate values to "reset"

---

For the price of less intuitive code... you get faster run times

***naive time test***

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create another group variable based on `is_blank` to reset the *cumsum*:

```
test_df['outval'] = (test_df.groupby([test_df.id, (test_df.is_blank.diff() != 0).cumsum()])
                     .is_blank.cumsum().groupby(test_df.id).shift().fillna(0))
test_df
```

[image]

*Break down*:

```
# create a group variable whose id increases when the blanks are not consecutive
g = (test_df.is_blank.diff() != 0).cumsum()
g

#0     1
#1     2
#2     2
#3     3
#4     4
#5     4
#6     4
#7     5
#8     5
#9     5
#10    6
#Name: is_blank, dtype: int64

# group data frame on both id and g, then do cumsum on the is_blank column
test_df.groupby([test_df.id, g]).is_blank.cumsum().groupby(test_df.id).shift().fillna(0)

#0     0.0
#1     0.0
#2     1.0
#3     2.0
#4     0.0
#5     1.0
#6     2.0
#7     0.0
#8     0.0
#9     0.0
#10    0.0
#Name: is_blank, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This answer gives weird output for this test case. Lets assume there is only one `id`. 
`is_blank =  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`; 
`outval=      [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`;

However, the desired output: 
`outval=[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

It seems to fail for cases when there are multiple 0s after a 1.

Comment: Try this `test_df['outval'] = (test_df.groupby([test_df.id, (test_df.is_blank.diff() != 0).cumsum()]).is_blank.cumsum().groupby(test_df.id).shift().fillna(0))`.

Comment: @Psiodom: this works well. I can see where the earlier one was going wrong. Do you want to update the main answer with this solution?